# Determine number of IPs within an IP range using Python 3 and Ipaddress module

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

Using the IPaddresss module and Python 3, how can I determine the number of IP addresses between the following IP range in string format:  "192.168.0.0-192.168.9.0" ?

It appears that the only arithmetic operators for adding/subtracting are in the following format:

```
ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.0') + x
ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.0') - x
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `ipaddress.summarize_address_range` can do what you want

```
>>> ip1 = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.0')
>>> ip2 = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.9.0')
>>> iprange = list(ipaddress.summarize_address_range(ip1, ip2))
>>> iprange 
[IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/21'), IPv4Network('192.168.8.0/24'), IPv4Network('192.168.9.0/32')]
```